# Spring-boot actuator doesn't publish hibernate metrics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-boot-actuator

There is a problem with actuator and hibernate metrics. Metrics are not generated by HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration. We have multiple hibernate connections and these settings out of application.properties (Configurated programatically usings beans)

In application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

In HibernateSessionHandler class:

```
    public HibernateSessionHandler setConfiguration(ConnectionConfig config) {
        this.configuration = new Configuration();
        this.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", config.getDriverClass());
        this.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", config.getHost());
        this.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", config.getLogin());
        this.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", config.getPassword());
        this.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", config.getDialect());
        this.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
        return this;
    }
```

HibernateSessionHandler - annotated as @Service and being extending by final connection beans.

We adhere to the concept creating and open connection only if in neccessary (our operations is just "select"), may be this is problem... i don't undarstand how to autoconfigure HibernateMetrics and HibernateQueryMetrics or how to update metrics when i'm creating  HibernateMetrics and HibernateQueryMetrics beans by myself

Please, help=)

Spring-boot version - 2.7.16
Hibernate-core version - 5.6.15.Final
Hibernate-micrometer version - 6.3.1.Final

I expect auto registration of HibernateMetrics and HibernateQueryMetrics when application started, but there is no hibernate metrics.

I tried to create beans returning HibernateMetrics in extending HibernateSessionHandler classes
In that case hibernate metrcis are created but not updated.
And i tried to set hibernate.generate_statistics=true via setConfiguration(ConnectionConfig config) method (example above)

**HOW I FIX IT**
To fix this problem, i had to change our app a bit. When we started developing our application, we agreed to create a SessionFacrory and a Session for each database request (We just read multiple databses whithout updating them), but it was the wrong way.
Firstly, this is not best practice.
Secondly, it worked quite slowly. As they say in a couple of stackoverflow queries- creating a SessionFactory - is a very expensive operation.

How did i fix it:

1. For all our connections, i had to create beans like this [problem](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1006#issuecomment-1058014616) in the implementation of the HibernateConncetion class marked as @Component
2. Deleted everything @Scope ("prototype") and made all components singleton
3. Added the use of c3p0 and hibernate-c3p0
4. Enabled "info" logging level for hibernate
5. Added to properties:

   ```
    this.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
    this.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5");
    this.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "20");
    this.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "200");
   ```

It seems to be working fine.

But the last question is - why does hibernate-c3p0-micrometer-actuator-spring not create metrics automatically (without self-creating MeterBinder beans) when the app is launched?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, worked by just adding `hibernate-micrometer` dependency.